# Windows 7 Remote Desktop Connection Magnification

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote-desktop, magnifier

I have a visual impairment which means I use tools such as `ZoomText` and the *magnifier tool*.

I need to RDC into another machine, but doing so removes any zooming ability, which is a real problem.

Now I'm doing this at work, which means I'm limited as to what I can do, I can't edit the registry for example.

The only zooming that works is the magnifier tool, but only in *dock* mode, I can't get it into *Full Screen*.

Both machines are running `Windows 7` with the `Aero Theme`.

Any ideas how I can get a full screen magnified view?

Comment: As you said this is at Work, you should contact your IT Department for these issue. As far as not being able to go into full screen is concerned, have you tried changing [RDC display settings](http://i.stack.imgur.com/26cil.png) ?

Comment: In many countries there are laws which mandates companies to make special provision for employees with disabilities. You should talk to your Manager/IT department/HR to resolve this issue.

Comment: Agreed, I wanted to make sure there was nothing 'I' could do to resolve the issue before hand.  I will email the IT department, but I'm sure they'll be scratching their heads over this one, as they have for most of may accessibility adjustments, I'm normally the one telling them how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this again, keeping zoomText active on the client machine and it seemed to work ok that time, I don't know what went wrong the first time, maybe a combination of having zoomText running on both machines, but I did get it working so all good, thank you for all the suggestions.